# How to enable User.Read.All for a single Exchange Online mailbox?

Tags: authentication, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-exchange

We have an app that allows scanning mailboxes in Exchange Online (Office 365). This app works fine, using the Microsoft Graph API `User.Read.All` permission to first fetch all users, and then `Mail.Read` to read their mailboxes.

**Problem**: One customer wants to restrict our app to work over a single mailbox, as a test of our app, without granting our app access to their whole tenancy.

It looks like this is possible using a "mail-enabled security group": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access . So the `Mail.Read` permission is not a problem.

But our app also lists users, so it needs the `User.Read.All` permission. I cannot figure out how to set this up for the "security group". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

AFIK, this is not possible yet. Profile access in AD cannot be restricted as mailbox access in Exchange. We are facing the same issue.